# Html is not changed in my backbone view after change data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have something like ordering function in backbone app...

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/orders/OrdersCollection',
    'text!templates/processing/processingTemplate.html'
], function(_, Backbone,OrdersCollection, processingTemplate){

  var ProcessingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#contents"),
    events : {
        'click .showProducts' : 'showProducts',
        'click .markDone' : 'markDone'
    },
    render: function(){

        var orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders'));
        var ordersCollection = new OrdersCollection(orders);
        var compiledTemplate = _.template( processingTemplate,{data :  ordersCollection.toJSON()} );
        $(this.el).html( compiledTemplate );
    },
    showProducts : function(event){

        var orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders'));
        var order_title = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-order');
        document.getElementById('orderTitle').innerHTML = order_title;
        var productsDiv = document.getElementById('products');
        productsDiv.innerHTML = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){
            if(order_title == orders[i].title){
                for(var j = 0; j < orders[i].items.length; j++){

                    if(orders[i].items[j].status == 0){
                        productsDiv.innerHTML += '<span class="orgestts"><li class="productcc">'+orders[i].items[j].title+'<a href="javascript:" class="right txtbt green markDone" data-ordertitle="'+order_title+'" data-itemtitle="'+orders[i].items[j].title+'" >Mark Done</a></li></span>';
                    }
                    else if(orders[i].items[j].status == 1){
                        productsDiv.innerHTML += '<span class="orgestts"><li class="productcc">'+orders[i].items[j].title+'<span class="right txtbt green" data-ordertitle="'+order_title+'" data-itemtitle="'+orders[i].items[j].title+'" >Done</span></li></span>';
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    markDone : function(event){

        var orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders'));

        var order_title = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-ordertitle');
        var item_title = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-itemtitle');
        event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Done';

        for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){
            if(order_title == orders[i].title){

                for(var j = 0; j < orders[i].items.length; j++){
                    if(item_title == orders[i].items[j].title){
                        orders[i].items[j].status = 1;
                    }

                }
                orders[i].status = '5';
                break;
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('orders',JSON.stringify(orders));
    }
  });

  return ProcessingView;
});
```

and in my template I have in class variable status :

```
<span class="ccstatus<%=order.status%>"><li class="menu showProducts" data-order="<%=order.title%>"><%= order.title %></li></span>
```

**class="ccstatus<%=order.status%>"**

So when I click to markdone button I have immediately changed status (class) in my data but not HTML or this style is not changed without reload page. So when I click to refresh this order after refresh have changed class like I need.

How can I change this class without refreshing whole app ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to collection changes and reflect that to dom yourself.

Change this:

```
render: function(){

    var orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders'));
    var ordersCollection = new OrdersCollection(orders);
    var compiledTemplate = _.template( processingTemplate,{data :  ordersCollection.toJSON()} );
    $(this.el).html( compiledTemplate );
},
```

to

```
initialize: function() {

    var orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders'));
    this.ordersCollection = new OrdersCollection(orders);

    this.listenTo(this.ordersCollection, "change", this.render, this);
},

render: function() {
             var compiledTemplate = _.template( processingTemplate,{data :  this.ordersCollection.toJSON()} );
    $(this.el).html( compiledTemplate );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now I have error  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'

Comment: `this` is supposed to be the view element can you console.log `this` and how do you instantiate the view? Alternatively you can use:
`this.ordersCollection.on("change" this.render, this)`;

Comment: I have this error when I solve version problem. 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a._listenerId') what do you think ?